# get all child elements under particular site using alfresco restAPI

Tags: directory, alfresco

i have created site ,name as testing under that created folder test.I am uploading images under test1 as sub folder under test by using rest API.i can get noderef of site by using url http://localhost:8081/alfresco/service/api/sites/testing

it give result like this
{
    "url": "/alfresco/service/api/sites/testing",
    "sitePreset": "site-dashboard",
    "shortName": "testing",
    "title": "Sample: Web Site Design Project",
    "description": "This is a Sample Alfresco Team site.",
    "node": "/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/b4cff62a-664d-4d45-9302-98723eac1319",
    "tagScope": "/alfresco/service/api/tagscopes/workspace/SpacesStore/b4cff62a-664d-4d45-9302-98723eac1319",
    "siteManagers":
    [
            "admin",
            "mjackson"
    ],
    "isPublic": true,
    "visibility": "PUBLIC"
}
but i tried to get children of this by giving url

http://localhost:8081/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/b4cff62a-664d-4d45-9302-98723eac1319/children

it give 404 error  please help this.I am using REST API

Comment: Works for me. 404 isn't an Alfresco error, you must have something about the path wrong.

Comment: I got the same problem. It gives me an Alfresco generated 404 error page telling me '02030035 Script url /api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/.../children does not map to a Web Script.'

Comment: Works for me against 4.2.f Community Edition